# How to filter arrays with multiple conditions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So my example array as follows,

```
{
    "available": [
        {
            "AC": "false",
            "availableSeats": "18",
            "avlWindowSeats": "10",
            "bookable": "true",
            "nonAC": "true",
            "seater": "false",
            "sleeper": "true",
            "zeroCancellationTime": "0",
            "mTicketEnabled": "true"
        },
        {
            "AC": "false",
            "availableSeats": "18",
            "avlWindowSeats": "10",
            "bookable": "true",
            "nonAC": "true",
            "seater": "true",
            "sleeper": "true",
            "zeroCancellationTime": "0",
            "mTicketEnabled": "true"
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

And my filter data as follows,

```
var filters = {
            nonAC: [
                "true"
            ],
            seater: [
                "true"
            ],
            sleeper: [
                "true"
            ],
        };
```

And i have created a query builder which helps to finalize the query !

```
buildFilter = (filter) => {
        let query = {};
        for (let keys in filter) {
            if ( (filter[keys].constructor === Object) || (filter[keys].constructor === Array && filter[keys].length > 0)) {
                query[keys] = filter[keys];
            }
        }
        return query;
    };
```

And finally my filter function as follows,

```
filterData = (data, query) => {
        const filteredData = data.filter( (item) => {
            for (let key in query) {
                if (item[key] === undefined || !query[key].includes(item[key])) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        });
        return filteredData;
    };
```

If you notice my filter conditions it says

```
seater: [
                "true"
            ],
            sleeper: [
                "true"
            ],
```

Which obliviously means that if seater and sleeper is true then filter that, but the problem is i need the result as "seater or sleeper" so, if any one is true it should filter that,

So how to change my filter function which accepts as seater or sleeper.

The result should give both the array as result not the second one alone as output !

Answer (score 0):

You coiuld get the entries of `filters` and filter if one of the filter is `true`.

```js
const
    available = [{ AC: "false", availableSeats: "18", avlWindowSeats: "10", bookable: "true", nonAC: "true", seater: "false", sleeper: "true", zeroCancellationTime: "0", mTicketEnabled: "true" }, { AC: "false", availableSeats: "18", avlWindowSeats: "10", bookable: "true", nonAC: "true", seater: "true", sleeper: "true", zeroCancellationTime: "0", mTicketEnabled: "true" }],
    filters = { nonAC: ["true"], seater: ["true"], sleeper: ["true"] },
    filterEntries = Object.entries(filters),
    result = available.filter(object =>
        filterEntries.some(([key, values]) => values.includes(object[key]))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: it works for particular condtion but if it changes means am not getting expected result, but for my use case there are few more conditions which i haven't included in filters, so can you please make changes on my filter function ?